# my data is messed up when using json.net to serialize DataTable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, visual-studio, json.net

I an using json.net to serialize my DataTable. I pass this json string (the result) to the view to render it in an unorder list. But json format is messed up in the result

DataAccess

```
public static string getClinic()
{
    string sproc = "getClinic";
    return callProcedure(sproc);
}

public static string callProcedure(string sproc)
{
    DataTable ds = null;

    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(sqlConnString))
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sproc, sqlConn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            sqlConn.Open();

            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

            ds = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(ds);

            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ds);
            return json;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{

    QueryModel qModel = new QueryModel {
        tblClinic = new Clinic(),

    };
    return View("Index", qModel);
}
```

View

```
<ul>
    @foreach (var p in Model.tblClinic.clinic){
        <li>@p</li>
    }
</ul>
```

But my data is messed up like this:

```
[
{
"
c
o
d
e
"
:
0
,
"
n
a
m
e
"
:
"
A"
}
,
{
...
}
```

I expect to be:

```
code: 0, name: A
code: 1, name: B
```

...

Do I need to deserialize the json object first before looping?

More information:
   my model

```
public class QueryModel
{
    public Clinic tblClinic { get; set; }

}
```

my domain

```
public class Clinic
{
    public string clinic { get; set; }
    public Clinic() {
        this.clinic = Data.getClinic();       
    }
}
```

Comment: We don't need to see all your different layers of code, just the part that is applicable to the question at hand. Input, output, and a minimally complete/testable example are what you need.

Comment: You write your json string's each char line by line, `@foreach (var p in Model.tblClinic.clinic){
                            <li>@p</li>
                        }`

Comment: It's doing exactly what you're telling it to.  The `<li>` adds a line break after each character you are iterating though.  The foreach has no idea you want to deserialize a JSON string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I need to deserialize the json object first before looping?

Yes, obviously. You need to **deserialize the json object first** before looping. Otherwise, looping through a `string` will only produce a `char` at each step.

Deserialization in the class may be something like:

```
public class RootObject // you have to set the class name
{
    public int code { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

Then in the View, you can loop like below:

```
<ul>
    @foreach (RootObject p in JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(Model.tblClinic.clinic))
    {
        <li>code: @p.code, name: @p.name</li>
    }
</ul>
```